# How to specify which database (not "master") in tsql (FreeDTS command line tool)

Tags: freetds

I am actually trying to connect to an MS SQL Server on Azure, from Python, via the module `pymssql` which relies on FreeTDS. I just can't make it work. I found the command line tool `tsql` which is supposedly for testing FreeTDS connections. And also, I can't connect with `tsql`. Regarding this, I have one very specific question.

How do I specify which "database" in the tsql tool. Fx if I use dbeaver, I must specify the database, "ava-iot". Using `man tsql` does not tell me how to specify another database.

When I try:

```
$  tsql -H uepbua32ii.database.windows.net -p 1433 -U Azure_SQL_Reader_Temporary -P XXXXXX
```

I get:

```
"The server principal "Azure_SQL_Reader_Temporary" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context."
```

This tells me, that it is specifically trying to connect to a database named `master`. So how do I tell it to try the database `ava-iot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your user `Azure_SQL_Reader_Temporary` has the default database set to be `master`. You can change that as well. But to answer your question of how to do it with `tsql` using the `-D` parameter.

```
tsql -H uepbua32ii.database.windows.net -p 1433 -D dbname -U Azure_SQL_Reader_Temporary -P XXXXXX
```

Good luck!

Comment: With my version of tsql, the man pages do not mention the -D parameter. Stupid :(